# Python Error handling: check if input to class in python is a string in desired format

Tags: python-3.x

So I have made a class Rubiks cube, and the string input it's supposed to take should be formatted as follows: "WWWW RRRR GGGG YYYY OOOO BBBB"

How do I make sure that is the case?

Comment: It's not clear what your format means. What do the `W` `G`, etc. mean? Can you give some examples of valid/invalid input and why they are valid/invalid?

Comment: The input is a string. So W means white and G means green. The string should be in the above string format. 
Invalid input would be ones with strings with letters other than the ones above, or any other data type, because those letters are the only ones that represent the colors of a rubiks cube

Comment: you should explain the question in more details.

Comment: I guess I was looking for something more like: "The string must have 4-Ws, 4-Gs...in any combination in groups of four separated by a space" That would be my guess of what you are after, but still not sure. Maybe part of the confusion is that a typical Rubik's Cube has 9 squares on each face and your format looks like it has 4.